# Is there a way to encrypt in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, encryption

How do I encrypt something in jQuery? 
I want to have the option to encrypt via 
SHA1 or MD5.

How do I do that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139053/encrypt-jquery-javascript-file

Comment: SHA1/MD5 are hash algorithms, not encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have list of plugins in this link :

http://www.jquery4u.com/security/10-jquery-security/

example to md5 :

https://github.com/gabrieleromanato/jQuery-MD5

Comment: first link is down. second link redirects to main jquery page

Answer (score 10):

```
function Encrypt(str) {
    if (!str) str = "";
    str = (str == "undefined" || str == "null") ? "" : str;
    try {
        var key = 146;
        var pos = 0;
        ostr = '';
        while (pos < str.length) {
            ostr = ostr + String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(pos) ^ key);
            pos += 1;
        }

        return ostr;
    } catch (ex) {
        return '';
    }
}

function Decrypt(str) {
    if (!str) str = "";
    str = (str == "undefined" || str == "null") ? "" : str;
    try {
        var key = 146;
        var pos = 0;
        ostr = '';
        while (pos < str.length) {
            ostr = ostr + String.fromCharCode(key ^ str.charCodeAt(pos));
            pos += 1;
        }

        return ostr;
    } catch (ex) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very usefull

Comment: This algorithm... is not cryptographically secure and has a [well known attack discovered at least in 9th century if not earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis).

Answer (score 3):

*This isn't a direct answer to the question, but considerations you should take into account with the overall approach:*

Though you *could* do *something* in jQuery, you should [use SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) if  at all possible, this is a much more secure way of passing information back and forth to the server if that's your goal.

Encrypting content via JavaScript but still sending it in plain-text really does nothing to thwart [man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), which while some people imagine to be rare because you must control some point in the connection...how many people use third-party WiFi, at the coffee house, etc?  Anywhere with a public hotspot is easy game for a man-in-the middle, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this proven library: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5

It's not a jQuery plugin - just call the functions as needed.