# Setting session variable with jQuery (without passing via Post or Get)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session-variables

So I have a page where I'm requesting users to enter a key via an `<input>` tag. I would like to store this information in `$_SESSION['sessionKey']` when the user clicks a button. Since I'm trying to keep the key moderately secure, I want to **avoid passing this information via GET or POST**.

Most of what I've found online shows this done by using GET/POST and I'm having difficulty finding information on a method that would not use this approach. I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365738/how-to-access-php-session-variables-from-jquery-function-in-a-js-file), which suggests to put JavaScript in a file that has an extension of .php, and from there, use the PHP tags to obtain the $_SESSION variables. I followed this approach like so...

**javascript.php**

```
<?php
require ("common/startandvalidate.php");
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        <?php $_SESSION['sessionKey']?> = $("#sessionKeyInput").value;
    });
});
```

**mainPage.php**

```
<head>
   <script src="javascript.php"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<input id="sessionKeyInput" placeholder="Session Key" />
<input id="submitButton" value="Submit" type="button" />
```

When I look at the page through Inspector (in Chrome) I see the error message:

```
Undefined index: sessionKey
```

the `require("common/startandvalidate.php");` contains `session_start()`, so the session is being initiated...

I think it's not working because `$_SESSION['sessionKey']` has never been declared before, so even though I want to assign a value to it, it's trying to see the variable contents, which is undefined. How could I go about assigning this value to the $_SESSION variable?

Sorry if this is a simple question, any resources are appreciated!

Comment: HTTP only handles GET, POST, HEAD, there is nothing else. Also keep in mind that PHP-generated files (CSS, JS, whatever) are not cached by the browser and are re-deownloaded and re-parsed everytime you reload the page.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of encryption before passing it?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486465/is-there-a-way-to-encrypt-in-jquery

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a PHP array, you cannot set it on the client side via javascript. The value has to be sent to the server to be stored in the array.

Comment: If you don't want to POST or GET the data then the only other alternative is to use cookies to store the data.

Comment: If you want security then add an ssl cert to your server and ensure that the client is connected via https....Then GET and POST all day.

Comment: I'll probably add SSL in the future, this is more of a "proof-of-concept" build though. Thanks everyone for the suggestions and clarification, I think I'll just go with encryption + salt via POST route.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you may want to rethink why you are creating this user-defined session key. The server side session context is kept secure by php internals using a cookie, there is no need to differentiate each session manually.

Comment: @ricksuggs Yes this key is not the same as the PHPSESSID cookie. It's along the lines (conceptually) of a chatroom, where users must enter a valid name a key to gain access. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is a PHP array, you cannot set it on the client side via Javascript. The value has to be sent to the server to be stored in the array.

**[The question you pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365738/how-to-access-php-session-variables-from-jquery-function-in-a-js-file)** shows how you can retrieve the data from `$_SESSION`, but it won't work for storing data.

The error you see in the console "Undefined index: sessionKey" simply means that the Javascript array named `$_SESSION` has no key named "sessionKey".

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I wasn't exactly sure how it would work storing the data, thanks for clearing that up though! I think I'll go with some other suggestions and encrypt it with a salt before sending it via POST. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript runs on the client and doesn't have access to the server, and therefore the session. If you want to put a user-entered value in the session, you need to pass it to the server. The most secure way to do that is an SSL-protected HTTP POST.